# No video with supported format and MIME type found

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, video, html5-video

So i have this video element on my website

```
<videogular vg-responsive="true" vg-theme="config.theme.url" vg-player-ready="onPlayerReady($API)" vg-complete="onCompleteVideo()" vg-theme="config.theme.url">
<vg-media vg-src="config.sources"
          vg-tracks="config.tracks"
          vg-native-controls="true">
</vg-media>
```

IF i view this in chrome there is no problem and the video is displayed

if however i view the same page in Firefox i get the following error:
No video with supported format and MIME type found

And in IE10 the video does not appear.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers support different video formats - the link below is a good overview but be aware this is a constantly changing area so it is worth rechecking regularly:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

The error message you are seeing on Firefox is consistent with it not supporting the video format in question (see the note on mp4 in the link above which is often a surprise, but note that many people will have downloaded a plugin to play mp4 even on earlier versions of Chrome).